# How to get the maximum value of an Eigen tensor?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I am trying to find the maximum value of an Eigen tensor. I know how to do this using Eigen matrices but obviously this is not working for a tensor:

Example

```
static const int nx = 4;  
static const int ny = 4; 
static const int nz = 4;

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Test(nx,ny,nz); 
Test.setZero();

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> MaxTest(nx,ny,nz); 
MaxTest.setZero();  
MaxTest = Test.maxCoeff();
```

Usually for an Eigen matrix I would do the following:

```
MaxTest = Test.array().maxCoeff();
```

But this is not working, instead I get the error:

```
class "Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3, 0, Eigen::DenseIndex>" has no member "maxCoeff"
```

Is there another way to get the maximum value of this tensor? Something equivalent to `max(max(max(tensor)))` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `maximum()`, see the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title57):

```
static const int nx = 4;  
static const int ny = 4; 
static const int nz = 4;

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> MaxTest(nx,ny,nz); 
MaxTest.setZero();  
Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> MaxAsTensor = MaxTest.maximum();
double Max = MaxAsTensor(0);
std::cout << "Maximum = " << max_dbl << std::endl;
```

Comment: So, this works with no errors ``Test.maximum();`` but this does not ``double max = Test.maximum();``

Comment: @Mathew77 Sorry, my mistake, `maximum()` returns something that yields a zero dimension tensor. You can then access its only element with `(0)`. See my edited answer.

Comment: I was looking for a way to extract the singleton from the [zero-dimension tensor](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title98) . Thanks for showing it! (although it feels strange to index into it).